# NDB Async API and get_or_insert_async

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to wrap my head around the async api, without much success.

I a fairly simple setup in my lab project. I have a model that looks like this:

```
class SearchIndex(model.Model):
    name = model.StringProperty(required=True)
    reference_list = model.KeyProperty(repeated=True)
```

And a method that uses get_or_insert and the checks if reference_list contains a key, if not add it. Below the entity is a model entity and list is a list of strings ["abc","def","ghi"]

```
@classmethod
    def store_list_in_index(cls, list, entity):
        put_queue = []

        for verb in list:
            index_entity = cls._SEARCH_INDEX_DB_MODEL.get_or_insert(verb, name=verb)
            if not entity.key in index_entity.reference_list:
                index_entity.reference_list.append(entity.key)
                put_queue.append(index_entity)

        if put_queue:
            ndb.put_multi_async(put_queue)
```

This worked as I wanted, but to a looong time. If the list was about 20-30 times long. It took about 15-20 sec.

So I started look at the async api. But don't get very far. Now it doesn't store any thing in the db:

```
@classmethod
def store_list_in_index(cls, list, entity):
    put_queue = []
    async_queue = []

    @tasklets.tasklet
    def txn(verb, entity):
        ent = yield cls._SEARCH_INDEX_DB_MODEL.get_or_insert_async(verb, name=verb)
        if not entity.key in ent.reference_list:
            ent.reference_list.append(entity.key)
            put_queue.append(ent)
        raise tasklets.Return(ent)

    for verb in list:
        en = txn(verb, entity)

    if put_queue:
        ndb.put_multi_async(put_queue)
```

I don't really understand where, mostly since I don't understand the concept of the tasklets and yield. Anyone have any idea or can point my in a direction?

**EDIT:**

I ended up with this solution:

```
@classmethod
@ndb.tasklet
def get_or_insert_index_entity(cls, verb):
    ent = yield cls._SEARCH_INDEX_DB_MODEL.get_by_id_async(verb)
    if not ent:
        key = ndb.Key(cls._SEARCH_INDEX_DB_MODEL, verb)
        ent = cls._SEARCH_INDEX_DB_MODEL(key=key, name=verb)
        yield ent.put_async()

    raise ndb.Return(ent)

@classmethod
@ndb.tasklet
def txn(cls, verb, entity):
    ent = yield cls.get_or_insert_index_entity(verb)
    if not entity.key in ent.reference_list:
        ent.reference_list.append(entity.key)
        yield ent.put_async()
    raise ndb.Return(ent)

@classmethod
def store_list_in_index(cls, list, entity):
    put_queue = []
    for verb in list:
        put_queue.append(cls.txn(verb, entity))
```

And adding @ndb.toplevel to my get-request handler. And it's way faster!

I also have posted this question on https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/appengine-ndb-discuss/L4DEsYdEwTE and included some follow up questions

Comment: I'm replying in some detail to the appengine-ndb-discuss list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't wait for the result to come back from your "ndb.put_multi_async(put_queue)", then your web handler might finish before it actually gets around to making the request. Check that put_multi_async function's return value. It's a list of Futures.

To wait for one Future to finish, you might say fut.get_result() (or fut.wait() if you don't care about the return value). If you have a bunch of futures, you probably want Future.wait_all wait_any described at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/futureclass.html

Comment: You're absolutely correct. But I ended up using @ndb.toplevel that I think do something similar. Updated the question with the solution I ended upp using.

Comment: The sad part is that I'm the tech writer who wrote the documentation that made it so hard to wrap your brain around this in the first place. So if you have suggestions on how to make that brain-wrapping easier, please speak up.

Comment: Mainly I would say what the different decorators do, and the difference between them. Also a few more examples. For instance best practice when to use tasklet and when use .get_result. This maybe not be the best place discus this. Couldn't find your email, but if you could drop me one (mail in profile) I have a few (I think) good ideas how to improve this.

Comment: Yes indeed, those are good ideas, thank you. I can't see an email address in your profile (maybe stackoverflow hides them to prevent abuse?), but if you have more to say, you can reach me at lahosken@google.com . Thank you!

Comment: probably :) I found you email address (som web+comments thing). But I'll resend it to your google address.